# Strange behaviour adding constraints to subview of UIScrollView within a UIStoryboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uistoryboard

I've got a view controller that contains a `UIScrollView` with the following hierarchy.

`- UIView
-- UIScrollView
---- UIImageView
---- UIButton
    ....`

When constraining the subviews of the `UIScrollView`, the right alignment is incorrect.

[image: Imgur]

My `UIScrollView` constraints:
[image]

`UIButton` constraints after creating trailing constraint
[image]

**What I've tried**
At first I thought it was just the storyboard not rendering the view controller properly. After an Xcode restart and a computer restart the issue persists.

Setting the `Adjusts Scroll View Insets` property on the containing view controller has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrollviews are a bit tricky, because they're made to scroll over their content both horizontally and vertically.

If you think about it, there's no way for the scrollview to know its content width, you have to set it. That's why your button is not where it should be.

If you want your view to scroll only vertically, you first have to set your content width to your scrollview's width (more exactly to your scrollview's parent's width).

The usual way to achieve this is to have a unique subview into your scrollView, and use it as a content view.
So, add a UIView to your scrollview, add it the constraints so that it fills the scrollview (ie top, leading, trailing and bottom spacing = 0).
Next, the most important constraint: add a width constraint so that your content view's width is equal to the scrollview's parent's width (in your case, probably your viewController's view.

And that's it. Now you can add any content you want into the content view. (your content view needs to have an height too, either a fixed height or constraints from the top to bottom)

[image: ScrollView Setup]

Comment: Thanks, it was the horizontal scrolling that got me!